# how to change default dateformat AAAA-MM-DD to dd/mm/yyyy in Django?

Tags: python, django, date-format

My locale dateformat is dd/mm/yyyy and Django is requering AAAA-MM-DD

when the user inputs 04/11/2009 Django raises:

```
_('Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format.'))
```

Im using simple html input field type="text", Not forms.DateField

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a `forms.DateField`. If so, you need to supply a `input_formats` argument like so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])
```

input_formats just takes a list of the formats you want to accept.

See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield for more information.

Comment: rich, I did your suggest and still the same problem: ValidationError
Exception Value: Introduzca una fecha válida en formato AAAA-MM-DD.

Comment: can you paste the full code? both from the forms.py and views.py?

Comment: there are a few things i noticed in your code that would have to be addressed before trying to pinpoint the ValidationError. most notably is_valid should be is_valid(). i've made mods to the pasted code (http://pastebin.com/d29e92c68) and highlighted important lines that i modified.

Comment: (pastebin.com/d29e92c68) Unknown post id, it may have expired or been deleted :( Did you put it to 1 day-expire?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's post and comments, it looks like there is more here than just using input_formats for the date field, though you'll want to do that.  The message 'Enter a valid date in YYYY-MM-DD format' is an exception and **NOT** a form validation error.  You'll get this exception if you try to save a model instance using a date string that is not 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

What is needed is to use a DateField in the form, and then instantiate the model using the cleaned data, which is a datetime object.  It looks like the OP was instantiating the model with a string rather than a datetime object.

This section of the Django docs discusses preparing DateField data:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#what-happens-when-you-save